# Can a github action use the search api?

Tags: github-actions, github-api

I'm trying to create a github action that searches all PRs in our repository with a specific label. The api call returns the correct result when running it locally with my personal access token but in the action it seems to get no results.

The default workflow permissions are "Read and write".

This is the action code:

```
name: Cleanup deploy-in-dev label

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  schedule:
    - cron: "15 1 * * *"

jobs:
  cleanup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Search label deploy-in-dev
        run: |-
          curl \
            -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
            -H "Authorization: Bearer ${GITHUB_TOKEN}" \
            -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
            "https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:private-org/example+is:pull-request+is:open+label:deploy-in-dev" \
            | grep "\"number\":" \
            | sed 's/.*"number": \([0-9]*\),/\1/g' \
            | while IFS= read -r pr_number; do
            echo "Found pr with label with pr number ${pr_number}"
          done
```

Could this be a permission error or do I miss something else?

Comment: The short answer is: yes, it can. However, when I was using it, it was with a different token than the `$GITHUB_TOKEN`. Try to change [permissions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#permissions) of the token inside the workflow file. Otherwise you could create a fine-grained personal access token, set it as a secret and then use it in your workflow.

Comment: Personal access tokens are not an option for use because we cannot have techical accounts due to company SSO limitations. I actually did access the provided token in a wrong way. It needs to be `${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}` instead of `${ GIHTUB_TOKEN }`. I posted the working action below.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great GH action - [GitHub Script](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-script). It allows writing scripts in your workflow and provides an easy and elegant way to run these scripts.

**Working example**:

```
name: Cleanup deploy-in-dev label

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  schedule:
    - cron: "15 1 * * *"

jobs:
  cleanup:
    name: Search and remove deploy-in-dev label
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      pull-requests: write

    steps:
      - uses: actions/github-script@v6
        name: Search and remove deploy-in-dev label
        with:
          script: |
            const label = 'deploy-in-dev';

            const pullRequests = await github.rest.pulls.list({
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              state: 'open'
            });

            console.log(`Found ${pullRequests.data.length} Pull Request(s)`);

            await Promise.all(pullRequests.data.map(async (pr) => {
              if (pr.labels.filter(l => l.name === label).length === 0) {
                console.log(`Skipping PR number ${pr.number}`);
                return;
              }

              console.log(`Removing label ${label} from PR number ${pr.number}`);

              await github.rest.issues.removeLabel({
                owner: context.repo.owner,
                repo: context.repo.repo,
                issue_number: pr.number,
                name: label
              });
            }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not use the `GITHUB_TOKEN` correct. It needs to be `${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}` instead of `${ GIHTUB_TOKEN }`. It works like this:

```
name: Cleanup deploy-in-dev label

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  schedule:
    - cron: "15 1 * * *"

jobs:
  cleanup:
    name: Search and remove deploy-in-dev label
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      pull-requests: read
    steps:
      - name: Search and remove label deploy-in-dev
        run: |-
          curl --silent \
            -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
            -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
            -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
            "https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:${{ github.repository }}+is:pull-request+is:open+label:deploy-in-dev" \
            | grep "\"number\":" \
            | sed 's/.*"number": \([0-9]*\),/\1/g' \
            | while IFS= read -r pr_number; do
            echo "Found pr with label with pr number ${pr_number}"
          done
```

As a bonus I added to minimal set of permissions to the action so that it still runs. The only permission needed is `pull-requests: read`. If the action should also be able to add or remove a label the permission needs to be `pull-requests: write`. The complete action I now use is this one:

```
name: Cleanup deploy-in-dev label

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  schedule:
    - cron: "15 1 * * *"

jobs:
  cleanup:
    name: Search and remove deploy-in-dev label
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      pull-requests: write
    steps:
      - name: Search and remove label deploy-in-dev
        run: |-
          curl --silent \
            -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
            -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
            -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
            "https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:${{ github.repository }}+is:pull-request+is:open+label:deploy-in-dev" \
            | grep "\"number\":" \
            | sed 's/.*"number": \([0-9]*\),/\1/g' \
            | while IFS= read -r pr_number; do
            echo "Removing label from pr number ${pr_number}"
            curl --silent \
              -X DELETE \
              -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
              -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"\
              -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
              https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/issues/${pr_number}/labels/deploy-in-dev
          done
```